# Download image for an item list view

Tags: android, list, android-asynctask

I'm trying to fill my list view.
Every item in my list view contain a text (title) and an image (thumbnail).
My images are downloaded from the server. So every time I add an item in my list view I check if my image already exist, if not I download it in an asynchron task. When the asynchron task finish execution, I put the downloaded image in my item list view.

```
private class Thumbnails extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
    {
        private Bitmap bitmap;

        private File fileTest;

        private String extStorageDirectory;

        @Override

        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values){

            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            Log.i("DocumentListItem","start downloading thumbnail = "+thumbnailURL);

            try{

                extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

                fileTest = new File(extStorageDirectory+"/AAAA/"+mDocument.getTitle()); 

                if(fileTest.exists()){

                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileTest.getAbsolutePath(), options);

                }
                else{

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(thumbnailURL).openConnection().getInputStream());

                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                if (bitmap != null){

                    bitmapThumbnail = bitmap;

                    mImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }

                if(fileTest.exists()){

                }else{

                    try {

                        File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "AppoxySavedFiles");

                        folder.mkdir();

                        File file = new File(folder, mDocument.getTitle());

                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

        }
    }
```

The problem is that Cover image thumbnails load randomly and are not properly associated with the right document item. Thumbnails rearrange themselves when scrolling up and down.

Do anyone have an idea what is wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is that your `mImage`, into which you are setting the image, is not defined within the asynctask, but elsewhere.  Most likely, you end up with more than one task running (for multiple list items) and the `mImage` variable gets messed up somewhere.  I suggest you actually pass it (or a reference to it in one way or another) into the asynctask as a parameter, thus guaranteeing that you'll be setting the picture into the right ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

there is a [blog](http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/06/android-development-tutorial-asynchronous-lazy-loading-and-caching-of-listview-images/) by cacois. he has post on asynchronous lazy loading images and caching them to the SD card, and put an example project on [github](https://github.com/cacois/TweetView).

it helped me in solving my problem. it also may help you out to solve your problem.